# Can't install windows 7 (no windows splash screen is showing up)

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows XP on my PC. I wanted to check out Windows 7 but I have a problem.

Namely, when I boot with my usb stick no windows 7 screen is showing up. Instead, it boots like usual - motherboard screen and then GRUB screen.

I have tested the iso on Virtual Box, it's working just fine. I have tried installing another OS from the same usb stick (Linux Mint), and there's no problem with it.

I've tried different burning methods: I've tried the official Microsoft tool and UltraISO on windows, and I've tried UltraISO, winusb and dd (with different bootsectors) on Ubuntu, still, no windows splash screen or something is showing up at booting.

I have set boot sequence to removable device -> hdd -> cd/dvd and I've tried F8 (boot menu) as well. My motherboard is ASUS M5a78l-m lx3.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by: boot from usb stick? FYI: windows 7 cannot be installed from flash media without serious modifications. You need to use the DVD you got when you bought windows 7. You did buy it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Burn the iso on a DVD using whatever program you want and then proceed as always but select to boot via dvd/cd first